# How to generate an integer random value within an interval, starting from random byte

Tags: c, random

I looked at the other answers I found, but they don't seem suitable to my case.

I am working with ANSI C, on an embedded 32bit ARM system.
I have a register that generates a random 8bit value (generated from thermal noise in the chip). From that value I would like to generate evenly distributed integer values within certain ranges, those are:

0,1,2,3,4,5

0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

"true" randomness is very important in my application, I need to generate white noise that could make a measurement drift.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking `RandomValue % SizeOfRange` will not produce a truly random value because in general the bucketing into the discrete possible values will be uneven.

I would suggest using a bit mask to ignore all bits outside the range of interest, then repeatedly getting a new random number until the masked value falls within the desired range.

For the range 0..5, look at the right-most 3 bits.  That will produce a value in the range 0..7.  "Reroll" results of 6 or 7.

For the range 0..9 look at the right-most 5 bits.  The range is 0..16.  Ignore results from 10..16.

As a real-word analog, think of trying to get a random number between 1 and 5 with a 6-sided die.  There is no "fair" algorithm to map a roll of 6 into one of the desired numbers 1..5.  Simply reroll a 6 until you get something in the desired range.

Masking high bits ensures that the number of "rerolls" is minimal.

Be sure to pay attention to any physical limitations on how often you can pull the special register and expect to get an entirely random value.

Comment: I made more or less the same considerations and attempts. I wanted to avoid "rerolls" because the random generator takes cpu time, but it's the most viable way. Thanks.

Comment: You can reroll fewer times if you use all the bits. 252 is divisible by 6 and 250 is divisible by 10, so for the first case you only need to reroll once out of 64 times, and for the second one about once out of 42. You implement the equivalent of % using look-up tables.